# need help data binding with Observables in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

Is this the correct way to bind data using Observables? if it is, what else is wrong with my code that makes the selectedCourse variable equal undefined?

```
    this.golfDataService
      .getGolfData(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.selectedCourse = data.data
        console.log(data.data)
      })
    setTimeout(function () { console.log(this.selectedCourse) }, 2000);
  }
```

I expect both console.log statements to return the same thing, but only the first console.log returns the data, which is an object with golf course information, but the console.log(this.selectedCourse) returns undefined.

Comment: change it to `setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.selectedCourse) }, 2000);` if its fast enought it will return correct value. If you use function it rebinds `this` to that function context not the component

Comment: you're creating a closure and a race condition, just not good practice all around, use arrow functions and don't rely on timers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function. Then again depending on how fast the getGolfData call is, you 'might' get the value logged. The point it, we shouldn't try to use timers to rely on getting the data, instead develop the code in event driven way.

```
this.golfDataService
  .getGolfData(id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.selectedCourse = data.data;
    console.log(data.data);
  });
setTimeout(() => console.log(this.selectedCourse), 2000);
```

Comment: I did not even think about that, thank you so much! I know to avoid timers, It was just a quick way to see if the data was even binding, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not subscribe `Observable` in component logic unless you explicitly `unsubscribe()` subscriptions.

A better approach (less code, less complexity, best performance) is to use `async` pipe provided by Angular.

```
 this.selectedCourse$ = this.golfDataService
      .getGolfData(id)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.data),
        tap(x => console.log(x))
      );
```

Then in template :

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCourse$ | async as selectedCourse">
  Hello {{selectedCourse}}
</div>
```

This approach has a lot of benefits like cleaner code, avoid memory leak, easy migration to `OnPush` change detection strategy and powerful usage of RxJS.